# How max-content and min-content are evaluated for a row aside to a big grid-area in CSS grid?

Tags: css, browser, css-grid

According to MDN docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows):

**min-content**

> Is a keyword representing the largest minimal content contribution of the grid items occupying the grid track.

So, in this example:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: max-content max-content max-content min-content;
  grid-template-areas:
    "one aside"
    "two aside"
    "three aside"
    "four aside"
}

.one {
  background: red;
  grid-area: one;
}

.two {
  background: green;
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  background: blue;
  grid-area: three;
}

.four {
  background: yellow;
  grid-area: four;
}

.aside {
  background: grey;
  grid-area: aside;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one">
    One
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    Two
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    Three
  </div>
  <div class="four">
    Four
  </div>
  <div class="aside">
    Aside <br>
    Aside <br>
    Aside <br>
    Aside <br>
    Aside <br>
    Aside <br>
    Aside <br>
    Aside <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the height value evaluated for the fourth row in order to get the "min-content" value?
What is the height of the fourth row of the *aside* grid-area that `min-content` evaluates?

https://jsfiddle.net/oygf360r/

EDIT after @temani-afif comments:

In order to clarificate the question.
I understand the behaviour of `min-content` in this case.
What I'd like to know, is how the browser **computes** this value since the **second column doesn't have any content in that row, because the content of the *aside* column belongs to all rows.**
Does the browser just ignore the *aside* column in this case for the comparison?
Or do these elements have any special value?

I'm labelling it as browser also, because maybe it's more related to it.

Comment: @Paulie_D the aside is playing a role in defining the height of the other "rows". Then the question is why the yellow one with min-content is the biggest one? try to change the order of min-content on the row-tempalte to see the behavior

Comment: @Paulie_D but why only the min-content one is expanding? try for example: `grid-template-rows: max-content min-content max-content min-content;` and you will see the second and fourth row expanding and not the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not wrong, it's an [edge case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_case), the situation is due to how elements on multiple Grid Tracks are handled *(by the browser implementation of the specification)* to determine grid sizing.

In your example the [algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#overview-sizing) to determine row allocated space failed to satisfy the repartition according to the `grid-template-rows` property value, so in Chrome currently (December 2021) all rows are set to auto:
[image]

If you set at least one row to 1fr, the algo dispatch correctly the space between the rows :

[image]

Difference between browsers to handle the issue:
(Currently Firefox do the same as Google Chrome)

[image]