# Why does grid area shrink other cells, even if it has enough space?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have very simple grid, with header, and two columns. The grid has a fixed width: `300px`, and the aside also has a fixed width: `100px`.

If I increase the `min-width` of the header more then `200px`, then the `aside` section shrinks.

Why? Supposedly, it can be grown to the width of both columns without change the width of the other columns.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, max-content) auto;
  grid-template-rows: max-content auto;
  grid-template-areas: "header header"
    "aside main";
}
header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-width: 250px;
  /* Why if min-width > 200, then the aside shrinks?? */
}
aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 100px;
}
main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <header>
    Header
  </header>

  <aside>
    Aside
  </aside>

  <main>
    Main
  </main>
</section>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a1zto75g/

Comment: hmm, again that `max-content` like in a previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58978463/8620333 ... I guess it's time to re-read the Spec

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. the same problem is *WITHOUT* ``max-content```. https://jsfiddle.net/ufh91kwd/

Answer (score 0):

It's a complex interaction between `minmax()`, `max-content` and the widths on your grid items.

Consider managing all sizing at the container level.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr; /* adjustment */
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;     /* adjustment */
  grid-template-areas: " header header " 
                        " aside main ";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <aside>Aside</aside>
  <main>Main</main>
</section>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v8ewz1d4/)

Comment: I Must use ```minmax``` because the actual width of the aside scetion is unknown.

Comment: Then use `auto`.

Comment: Thanks. It is a good solution for my particular case, but I want also to understand this behavior.

Comment: ```grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, min-content) 1fr;``` is the best solution for my particular case. https://jsfiddle.net/9xjc3451/

Answer (score -1):

I Have a workaround: Set `order: 1;` for the aside. Then, the grid calculates the `width` of other sections, then it puts the aside correctly.

Very strange.

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 100px) auto;
  grid-template-rows: 30px auto;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "aside main";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-width: 250px;
  /* Why if min-width > 200, then the aside shrinks?? */
}

aside {
  order: 1;
  /* THIS IS THE WORKOROUND */
  grid-area: aside;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 100px;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <header>
    Header
  </header>

  <aside>
    Aside
  </aside>

  <main>
    Main
  </main>
</section>
```

Comment: you are having an overflow and we no more see the main element

Comment: hmmm... you are right. this is the same weirdness. Why the ```min-width``` of the header effect the width of the main section?!

Comment: there is a complex logic behind, still don't have all the pieces of the puzzle. When I do, I will write an answer ... as a side note, you are also having an overflow in your initial example. Add z-index to aside and you will have the same result like you did with order.